# iOS 7.1 [UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor override not working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, ios7.1

To change the barTint color programmatically I've created an own UINavigationBar class which extends the UINavigationBar. There I override the methode setBarTintColor to change the color. In iOS 7.1 this method is never called so I now call it manually from the "awakeFromNib" method but I think this is were the problem begins.

I use this custom class to override the following appearance setting:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.302 alpha:1.000]];
```

With this method in my custom class:

```
- (void)setBarTintColor:(UIColor *)barTintColor
{
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if(![NachtModusController NachtModus])
    {
        if (device.platformType == UIDevice4iPhone || device.platformType == UIDevice4SiPhone)
        {
            [super setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.000 alpha:1.000]];
        }
        else
        {
            [super setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.000 alpha:0.800]];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Nachtmodus.
        if (device.platformType == UIDevice4iPhone || device.platformType == UIDevice4SiPhone)
        {
            [super setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.302 alpha:1.000]];
        }
        else
        {
            [super setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.302 alpha:0.900]];
        }

    }
}
```

I've found out that:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

Didn't got called in 7.1 but:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarPosition:(UIBarPosition)barPosition barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

Is.

How can I override the setBarTintColor appearance setting with a custom class?

MY SOLUTION:

Seems that setting an image like this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

And resetting it like this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Is also causing some side effects in iOS7.1 (well differently then 7.0)

I removed the background image and I'm only using the barTint color which I change with the appearance option and change the current (self.navigationController.navigationbar).

I removed my custom class.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't overwrite `setBarTintColor:` in order to change the `barTintColor`. In your case, you 'destroy' the functionality of the `setBarTintColor:` method, as it ignores the input parameter. Furthermore your `NavigationBar` won't change the color as you intended, as long as you don't call the `setBarTintColor:` function.
You should move this code to a position, where it get's called, when the navigation bar is created. Either call it from outside, after you created the `NavigationBar`, or you overwrite the initializing method in your `NavigationBar` class.

Comment: When I call the setBarTintColor: from the three "init" methods or from awakeFromNib it doesn't work. What method should I use ?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? A white `NavigationBar`? Then you shouldn't subclass the `NavigationBar`, but call `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.000 alpha:1.000]]` from a `viewController` (maybe `viewDidLoad` method) wich is inside the `NavigationController`.

Comment: I want a simple way to style the navigationbar based on the current time of the day and always on the same way without redundant code. for example black when night and blue during the day. I achieve this easily by setting the custom class in Interfacebuilder and in iOS7.0 i could override the appearance settings.

Comment: Having the same problem overriding the setTintColor and setBackgroundImage in order to create a header color that is not faded but at a specific alpha, also to create a background image layer on some views that repeats the background instead of just stretching the image.